# In MVC, how do I return items in and Entity database using a range of dates from Javascript Calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, calendar, date-range

I want to get a range of items between dates from two JQuery calendars and then update the view when I press a submit button so that I only see the items between the selected dates. I'm not sure I'm going about things the best way.

My plan was to:

1. Get the user to select the dates in the calendars.
2. Use Javascript to return the dates as variables.
3. Send the variables to a controller which would then return a new view.

My code is below and **my question** is really in two parts.

1. Is there a better way to do this?
2. If this is ok, how can I get the javascript variables into the ActionLink to pass back to the controller?

Thanks in advance!

**Controller:**

```
        // GET: Home
    public ActionResult IndexDateRange(string sortOrder, DateTime startDateFromJS, DateTime endDateFromJS)
    {
        var sortedByDates = from pay in db.DailyPayments
                            select pay;
        sortedByDates = sortedByDates.OrderByDescending(pay => pay.Date);
        var first = sortedByDates.Select(pay => pay.Date).First();
        var lastDate = sortedByDates.Select(pay => pay.Date).Last();


        if (startDateFromJS > first.Date || (endDateFromJS < lastDate))
        {

            var dateRange = sortedByDates.Where(pay => pay.Date >= startDateFromJS && pay.Date <= endDateFromJS);
            return View(dateRange.ToList());
        }

        return View(sortedByDates.ToList());

    }
```

**Javascript in the Index:**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Get Dates", "IndexDateRange", routeValues: new { startDateFromJS = startDate, endDateFromJS = endDate }) 



<script>

    $(function () {
        var startDate = getStartDate();
        var endDate = getEndDate();

        function getStartDate() {

            $('#startDate').datepicker();
            $('#calendarSubmitButton').click(function () {
                //var startDate = $('#startDate').datepicker('getDate');
                var startDate = $('#startDate').datepicker('getDate');
                console.log(startDate);
                return startDate;
            })      

        };
        function getEndDate() {
            $('#endDate').datepicker();
            $('#calendarSubmitButton').click(function () {
                var endDate = $('#endDate').datepicker('getDate');
                console.log(endDate);
                return endDate;

            })               

        };
```

**Temporary Test JS to try and wire up the href. When I click on it, it just adds the pound symbol to the home/index Url and in the browser developer tools it says illegal character.**

```
<a href="#" id="calendarSubmitButton">Get Dates</a>

<script type="text/javascript">

        $('#calendarSubmitButton').click(function() {
            var tempStartDate = @DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).ToString("yyyyMMdd");
            var tempEndDate = @DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");

            location.href='@Url.Action("IndexDateRange")+'?startDateFrom‌​JS='+$('tempStartDate')+'&endDateFromJS='+$('tempEndDate')';

        });
</script>
```

**Screen Grab:**

[Screenshot of the setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0Ftn.jpg)

Comment: Your use of `@Html.ActionLink()` wont work because your adding the initial values of `startDate` and `endDate` as route values (not the edited values). You need javascript to generate a new url, e.g. you could handle the click event of the link and use `location.href='@Url.Action("IndexDateRange")+'?startDateFromJS='+$('#startDate').datepicker('getDate')+'&endDateFromJS'+.....` and the link can be just `<a href="#" id="getdates">Get Dates</a>`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks very much. That's really helpful. I'm having a bit of trouble getting the query string to work (illegal character somewhere), but I'm sure I just made a mistake. I'll try again in the morning with fresh eyes. Thanks again!

Comment: I wired this up as suggested by @StephenMuecke but I'm still having a bit of trouble getting things to work. I think I may not be formatting the query string correctly. Currently on a click handler I have: 

location.href='@Url.Action("IndexDateRange")+'?startDateFrom‌​JS='+$('#startDate')‌​.datepicker('getDate‌​')+'&endDateFromJS'+‌$('#endDate').datepicker('getDate')';

But I'm getting an illegal character error. Do I need to escape something?

Comment: What does `$('#startDate‌​')‌​.datepicker('get‌​Date‌​')` etc return? And what is the resulting url your generating? Best to edit you question with what you have tried

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've been working on this for the past three days in my free time trying to get it to work with your thoughts so I wouldn't have to come back here shame-faced, but no luck. I can't get the href to work, as stated above. I hardcoded everything just to try and test it, but I want it to send a string representation of the date to the controller as shown.  The URL is just appending a #. I'm sure I'm just making some dumb mistake. Updated with some test javascript at the bottom of my original post.

Comment: Thanks again for your help! It really set me on track in terms of what my main problem was.

Comment: I have rolled back your last edit. You cannot edit the question to show the correct code (its would not be a question any more and answers belong in the answers section) You have accepted an answer meaning that solved your problem. If you have other info to add, you can always add your own answer.

Comment: Okay, I'll do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of @StephenMuecke and @Tanmay, I was finally able to get this to work. I'm posting the functioning code here.

**Controller**

```
// GET: Home
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string startDate, string endDateFromJS)
{
    var sortedByDates = from pay in db.DailyPayments
            select pay;
    sortedByDates = sortedByDates.OrderByDescending(pay => pay.Date);

    if (startDate != null && endDateFromJS != null)
    {
        DateTime convertedStartDateFromJS = DateTime.ParseExact(startDate, "yyyyMMdd", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
        DateTime convertedEndDateFromJS = DateTime.ParseExact(endDateFromJS, "yyyyMMdd", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
        var dateRange = sortedByDates.Where(pay => pay.Date >= convertedStartDateFromJS && pay.Date <= convertedEndDateFromJS);

        return View(dateRange.ToList());
    }


    return View(sortedByDates.ToList());

}
```

**Javascript and HTML in the index.cshtml**

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Total payment:", new { id = "totalTextbox" }) <br />
    @Html.TextBox("Total", Math.Floor(totalPayment) + " yen" , new { @class = "alert alert-danger", @readonly = "readonly" })

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Starting Date:")
    @Html.TextBox("Starting Date:", "", new { @class = "date-picker", id = "startDate" })

    @Html.Label("Ending Date:")
    @Html.TextBox("Ending Date:", "", new { @class = "date-picker", id = "endDate" })


    @*<input type="submit" href="#" id="calendarSubmitButton" class="btn btn-primary"  />*@
    <a href="#" id="calendarSubmitButton">Get Dates</a>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {


            $('#calendarSubmitButton').click(function () {
                //TODO: Figure this out.
                var tempStartDate = $("#startDate").val($.datepicker.formatDate('yymmdd', new Date($('#startDate').datepicker('getDate'))));
                var tempEndDate = $("#endDate").val($.datepicker.formatDate('yymmdd', new Date($('#startDate').datepicker('getDate'))));


                location.href = '@Url.Action("Index")?startDate=' + tempStartDate.val() + '&endDateFromJS=' + tempEndDate.val();

            })
        });

    </script>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a href="#" id="calendarSubmitButton">Get Dates</a>

<script type="text/javascript">

        $('#calendarSubmitButton').click(function() {
               var tempStartDate = '@DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).ToString("yyyyMMdd")';
               var tempEndDate = '@DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")';

             location.href='@Url.Action("IndexDateRange")?startDateFrom‌​JS='+tempStartDate +'&endDateFromJS='+tempEndDate;

        });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! This really, really helped me with the syntax. Most appreciated.